# How to write REST APIs and provide authentication to android users using REST API's to an existing web application?

Tags: java, android, rest, authentication, spring-security-oauth2

we have a web application built using java. 
Now we want expand our services to android application via REST API's. 
I am completely new to android application and REST as well. 
Could somebody please help me on how we can provide authentication to android users via REST? any help as to start will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd start off by researching OAuth: https://oauth.net/2/

Comment: You can use php to create your REST apis on your server side. On android side you can make call to those REST apis and get data in form of JSON using libraries like volley. As you have said that you will be using for login and signup purpose you can encrypt the data using hashing (Guava library).

Comment: @davehenry thanks for the link. I will surely go through it. still could you please provide some sample code which could help me to a better start?

Comment: @SayokMajumder, sorry we have to write in Java as our application written in java.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post a [mcve].